# After installing Ubuntu the laptop starts Windows

Tags: system-installation, software-installation

I just bought a refurbished Thinkpad X220.

When I install Ubuntu I always select the option to erase the hard disk as I dont want any Windows on it. After installing I restart the laptop but Windows come back. I already tried to install it 5 times.

Any idea on how to solve this problem?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Does it have more than one hard disk? Are you using BIOS or UEFI boot? Does Windows boot fully (like, is the OS intact)?

Comment: How can I check this Bios or Uefi? I only have one hard drive and Windows boot fully.